# How to know if the user has pressed power key twice or thrice continuously outside the activity in android?

Tags: android, key, listener

I need to know when the user will press the power key continuously 2 or 3 times.
But in the case the user is out of the application lets say on the home screen or even using any other application.

I getting the listener event of the power key on the activity but not on the service.

```
   @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER == event.getKeyCode()){

        Log.e("POWER", "pow");
          return true;//If event is handled, falseif 

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

How can i know if the user has pressed the power button outside the activity?

Comment: There is something else which works for me absolutely fine
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609008/android-count-power-button-clicks-and-start-activity

Answer (score 3):

You cannot override the power button press from your application. But when you press power button the screen turns on/off. So you can detect this using a broadcast receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and a broadcast receiver class

```
public class MyBroadCastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            //Take count of the screen off position
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            //Take count of the screen on position
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: How do i call the broadcast....I suppose I am missing some intent action here....I put log in the if-else part but dun seem to go froward

Comment: No need to call broadcast receiver. Just write the class and define the receiver in manifest file(the first code). Now whenever the screen mode chenges the receiver will be triggered.

Comment: if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            //Take count of the screen off position
         Log.e("POWER", "off");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            //Take count of the screen on position
         Log.e("POWER", "on");
        }