# Count the times that the power button is pressed

Tags: java, android, button, screen

I'm new in developing Android apps, what I want to do is create an application which can read the times that the power button was pressed, to make an accessibility app.

Maybe if I can control or count the SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF events this could be helpful.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029978/how-to-detect-device-power-button-press-twice-in-android-programmatically

Comment: SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF receiver may not properly work, because the screen turns off automatically too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for the answer and found this

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        MyReceiver mReceiver = new MyReceiver (this);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Receiver.java

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static int countPowerOff=0;
    private Activity activity=null;
    public MyReceiver (Activity activity)
    {
    this.activity=activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      Log.v("onReceive", "Power button is pressed.");

      Toast.makeText(context, "power button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
             .show();

     if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) 
{
    countPowerOff++;    
} 
else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) 
{
      if(countPowerOff==5)
      {
          Intent i =new Intent(activity,NewActivity.class);
          activity.startActivity(i);
       }
    }

}
```

I found this answer from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609008/android-count-power-button-clicks-and-start-activity)
hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! This will help a lot!

Comment: glad I could be of help:)

Comment: Now I need to get it to run in background......