# how to detect power button event at lock screen android 9.1 honor mobile device

Tags: java, android

how to detect  power button at lock screen android 9.1 honor mobile device
I want to control my power button at lock screen for performing a particular task when the long press of power button in android devices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Count Power button clicks and Start Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609008/android-count-power-button-clicks-and-start-activity)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this with a `BroadcastReceiver` listening for `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF/Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` or overriding a `dispatchKeyEvent` for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER`.

Comment: Are you trying to send it or listen for it?